# pyplot how to do side-by-side plots when one is a line graph and the other is a 3d graph

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to do side-by-side plots of accelerometer data. I found [this code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python) for how to do two line graphs side-by-side, but I want a three-line line graph beside a 3-d plot of the same data.

I have working code for doing both separately and tried to modify it with the two subplot method calls as shown here:

```
import csv
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# not shown here: lists x, y, z are populated from a csv file 
# and strings type & filename are set

idx = np.array(idx,dtype=int)
x = np.array(x,dtype=float)
y = np.array(y,dtype=float)
z = np.array(z,dtype=float)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.subplot(1,2,1) # <--attempt
ax.plot3D(x, y, z, 'black')
ax.scatter(x[0],y[0],z[0], c='green', marker='*', s=50)
ax.scatter(x[-1],y[-1],z[-1], c='red', marker='*', s=50)
ax.set_title(type)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(idx,x, label = "x")
plt.plot(idx,y, label = "y")
plt.plot(idx,z, label = "z")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.savefig(filename+"-"+type+".png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

But when the plot is shown I get two windows, one labeled Figure 1 and empty, and another labeled Figure 2 with the line graph. The saved file contains only the line graph.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issues is because you are creating two separate figures instead of one figure with two subplots.

```
import csv
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# not shown here: lists x, y, z are populated from a csv file 
# and strings type & filename are set

idx = np.array(idx,dtype=int)
x = np.array(x,dtype=float)
y = np.array(y,dtype=float)
z = np.array(z,dtype=float)

# This line
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2) 

ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax1.plot3D(x, y, z, 'black')
ax1.scatter(x[0],y[0],z[0], c='green', marker='*', s=50)
ax1.scatter(x[-1],y[-1],z[-1], c='red', marker='*', s=50)
ax1.set_title(type)

ax2.plot(idx,x, label = "x")
ax2.plot(idx,y, label = "y")
ax2.plot(idx,z, label = "z")
ax2.legend(loc="best")

plt.savefig(filename+"-"+type+".png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. That put them on the same figure, but with the 3D graph overprinting  the line graph. I guess it needs to know which subplot to assign each to. I tried adding the subplot method calls as in the original but got error 'Axes3D' object has no attribute 'subplot'